# How to show value 0 when iam using DateFormatString {0:#,#.##} in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Grid View where Iam using DateFormatString {0:#,#.##} for one coloumn.
If column has value 0 it is not showing any values Could You please help me on this.

Here is my Code

```
   <asp:BoundField DataField="CummPV" HeaderText="Cumm-PV" SortExpression="cummPV" DataFormatString="{0:#,#.##}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cummEV" HeaderText="Cumm-EV" SortExpression="cummEV" DataFormatString="{0:#,#.##}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cummDelay" HeaderText="Cumm-Delay" SortExpression="cummDelay" DataFormatString="{0:#,#.##}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SPI1" HeaderText="SPI-1" SortExpression="SPI1" DataFormatString="{0:F3}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SPI2" HeaderText="SPI-2" SortExpression="SPI2" DataFormatString="{0:F3}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
```

For CummDelay coloumn it happens.

Comment: check if Cumm-Delay value is 0 or NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue us use of `#` placeholder at first digit place - # does not print the digit (if zero or does not exist). Use 0 instead to force the digit.

For example, use format string as `{0:#,0.##}` - this will print 0 for 0 value.

Another way would be to use 3 section format expression - sections are separated by `;` - the first is used for +ve values, second for -ve and last for zero values. That way you can control what exactly you wish to print for zero value. For example, you can use expression such as `{0:#,#.##;#;Zero}` to print `Zero` for 0 value.

See documentation for all details - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx